# Why does my NuGet package not add some referenced NuGet packages as dependencies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependencies, nuget

I am currently trying to create a NuGet package from an ASP.NET MVC project (let's call it Library) I created, that should act as a base for other ASP.NET MVC projects.

Almost everything works fine so far, the only problem I ran into is, that NuGet only includes some of the NuGet references of my "Library" project, most notably the ASP.NET MVC NuGet packages seem to be missing.

This is the list of packages in my "Library" project:
[image: NuGet packages in "Library" project]

And this is the dependencies created for the NuGet package:
[image: NuGet dependencies]

Does anyone have an idea why bootstrap, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc and others are not included?

Comment: Did you [specify the dependencies](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#specifying-dependencies) in the `.nuspec` file?

Comment: No I didn't. Afaik the dependencies should be detected automatically (as most of them already are).

Comment: How are you creating the package? Using NuGet pack? Using Package Manager Console?

Comment: I use NuGet pack and I am supplying it with the csproj file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just debugged the NuGet.exe and found out why this happens: apparently NuGet does not take ALL dependencies but only a minimal set. This minimal set consists only of top-level packages (=> packages that are not referenced by another package in the project).

So for example the `Autofac.Mvc5` package depends on `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` and therefore only `Autofac.Mvc5` is used as a dependency.

Comment: Thank you for investigating. So, actually, everything's perfect as-is?

Comment: Well I wouldn't exactly say perfect (see https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2376 for details), but at least I know why it's happening now :).